# Bookmarklet doesnt working on Mozilla but does in chrome

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, getelementbyid

i wrote this bookmarklet

```
<a href="javascript:var m = document.getElementById('xxx'); m.value=17;">test</a>
```

and it is working in Chrome, but not in Mozilla Firefox

i even tried

```
<a href="javascript:var m = document.getElementById('xxx'); m.value='17';">test</a>
```

but it doesn't work too

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did the solution that I provided work for you?

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps I recommend for making bookmarklets:

#### 1. Put everything in an immediately invoked function

You can use `(function(){YOUR CODE}());` or `(function(){YOUR CODE})();`

#### 2. Minify your code

You can use an [online JavaScript uglifier](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs)

#### 3. URL-encode it

You can use an [online URL-encoder](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)

In your case it could be something like this:

```
(function(){m=document.getElementById('xxx');m.value=17}());
```

encoded as:

```
(function()%7Bm%3Ddocument.getElementById('xxx')%3Bm.value%3D17%7D())%3B
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XMF6s/).

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because FF expects to follow the link to somewhere. This piece of code works

```
<a href="javascript:void(document.getElementById('xxx').value=17)">test</a>
```

But consider making your code unobtrusive. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0) may help you

Comment: You can't really have an unobtrusive bookmarklet. All of the code has to be `<a href="javascript:HERE">...</a>`. It's a good advice fo any non-bookmarklet JavaScript link, though.

Comment: It`s not about the bookmarklet. It is in general - thus the code is easyer to read, maintain, reuse etc.